# What is the value of this continued fraction?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

I am curious about the value of the continued fraction $$1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{5+\cfrac{1}{6+\dots}}}}}.$$

1. Can we evaluate it ?
2. Is it a nice value ?

Clearly it should be a transcendental number. But I have no idea about calculate it.

Comment: Here is some info that is a little beyond my comprehension at this hour.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFractionConstant.html

Comment: It has a quite surprising (at least to me) nice value as a ratio of Bessel functions: $\frac{I_{0}{(2)}}{I_{1}{(2)}}$. I don't have any idea how to demonstrate this though. See [WRA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=BesselI[0%2C2]%2FBesselI[1%2C2]).

Comment: I thought people newer thought about this continued fraction. But I was wrong :) I found a [similar continued fraction](http://www.math.ohio-state.edu/~edgar/contfrac.gif) which may be related to this one.

Comment: @turkeyhundt: Rather than this question be tagged as "unanswered", can you modify your comment to an answer? After all, you found: 1) its name, 2) the link provides the evaluation, and 3) it seems to have a "nice" value.

Comment: @turkeyhundt: As Tito Piezas III says, Please convert your comment to an answer. I'l accept it:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the info on this continued fraction and others.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFractionConstants.html