# Other "natural" simple continued fractions with closed-forms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, closed-form, continued-fractions

Given the [simple continued fraction](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularContinuedFraction.html),

$$x =b_0 + \cfrac{1}{b_1 + \cfrac{1}{b_2 + \cfrac{1}{b_3 + \ddots}}} $$

for some well-defined sequence of **positive** integers $b_k$ for $k>0$. More compactly, for $b_0 = 0$,

$$x = [0\color{red}{;}b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots]$$

we compile some old results from MSE. The first three have closed-forms, and we inquire about the last three. Let $I_n(x)$ be the "modified Bessel function of the first kind".

---

**I.** The $b_k$ as multiples of all positive integers.

$$D_1 =\cfrac{1}{1m +\cfrac{1}{2m + \cfrac{1}{3m  + \ddots}}}   = \frac{I_1(2/m)}{I_0(2/m)}\qquad$$

See [this 2015 post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087298/what-is-the-value-of-this-continued-fraction) for $m=1$, or [A073821](https://oeis.org/A073821) for $m=2$, or this [Mathworld article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFractionConstants.html).

---

**II.** The $b_k$ as multiples of all odd integers.

$$D_2 =\cfrac{1}{1m +\cfrac{1}{3m + \cfrac{1}{5m  + \ddots}}}  = \frac{I_{1/2}(1/m)}{I_{-1/2}(1/m)} =\frac{e^{2/m}-1}{e^{2/m}+1} = \operatorname{tanh}(1/m) $$

See [a 2014 post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079732/how-find-this-continued-fraction-1-3-5-7-9-11-cdots-value) for $m=1$, this [Mathworld article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/eContinuedFraction.html) for $m=2$, or [a 2019 post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3476817/4781) for general $m$.

---

**III.** The $b_k$ as multiples of $4n+1$.

$$D_{3a} =\cfrac{1}{1m + \cfrac{1}{5m + \cfrac{1}{9m + \ddots}}} = \frac{I_{1/4}\big(\tfrac{1}{2m}\big)}{I_{-3/4}\big(\tfrac{1}{2m}\big)}\quad$$

For multiples of $4n-1$, then $D_{3b}=\dfrac{I_{3/4}\big(\tfrac{1}{2m}\big)}{I_{-1/4}\big(\tfrac{1}{2m}\big)}.\,$ See [A308741](https://oeis.org/A308741) and [A308742](https://oeis.org/A308742).

---

**IV.** The $b_k$ as squares. (From [a 2020 post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632349/continued-fraction-using-all-perfect-squares).)

$$D_4 =\cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{4 + \cfrac{1}{9 + \ddots}}} =\;??$$

---

**V.** The $b_k$ as primes. (From [a Sept 2011 post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63865/a-continued-fraction-involving-prime-numbers).)

$$D_5 =\cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{3 + \cfrac{1}{5 + \ddots}}} =\;??$$

---

**VI.** The $b_k$ as composites. (From [a Nov 2011 post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83165/a-continued-fraction-involving-composite-numbers).)

$$D_6 =\cfrac{1}{4 +\cfrac{1}{6 + \cfrac{1}{8 + \cfrac{1}{9 + \ddots}}}} =\;??$$

---

**Question:** In the intervening years, has progress been made for the last three continued fractions, or for others using various sequences like the Fibonacci numbers or factorials?

**Note**: The first three have $b_k$ in arithmetic progression, hence can be expressed by the modified Bessel function. However, $D_4$ uses a *quadratic* sequence $b_k$ while the last two use "sieved sequences", thus understandably will be difficult, though one may hope for a closed-form.

Comment: Have you tried putting the values into something like Plouffe's inverse symbolic calculator?

Comment: @MJD I have, though there seems to be something wrong with my laptop or the Wayback Machine. I tried also Wolfram. (However, in the linked posts, I believe those were among the first things they did years ago.)

Comment: @MJD I decided to revisit this topic after we resolved a non-simple cfrac in a [recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833174/natural-continued-fraction) using the _error function_. Ironically, a simple cfrac may turn out to be more challenging than the non-simple ones.

Comment: You post the most interesting questions!  I see no reason to think $D_5$ or $D_6$ have a closed form answer.  However, $D_4$ is interesting. It should be possible using known methods. I will think about that one.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for the nice remark. I too think that $D_4$ may be more amenable, and some comments from the linked post also are of the same opinion. But it may need something more exotic than the Bessel function.

Answer (score 2):

There's also
$$ \tan(1/k) = \dfrac{1}{k-1+ \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{3k-2 + \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{5k-2 + \dfrac{1}{1+\ldots}}}}}}$$

Answer (score 2):

*comment*
On $D_4$.  Well, I was too optimistic.  The usual method—Kapitel 11 Satz 8 of

*Perron, Oskar*, [**Die Lehre von den Kettenbrüchen.**](https://oeis.org/A308720), Leipzig - Berlin: B. G. Teubner. xiii, 520 S. (8^\circ) (1913). [ZBL43.0283.04](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:43.0283.04).

—works, and yields a value.  But that value does not involve "well-known" functions.

$$
D_4 = \frac{\varphi(1)}{\psi(1)} \approx 0.804 ,
$$
where $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are solutions of the differential equation
$$
 \left( -{x}^{3}+{x}^{2} \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{4} y}{{\rm d}{x}^{4}}}
 - \left( 4\,{x}^{2}-4\,x \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{3
}y}{{\rm d}{x}^{3}}} - \left( -2+2\,x \right) {\frac 
{{\rm d}^{2}y}{{\rm d}{x}^{2}}} -y =0
$$
with $\varphi(0)=0, \varphi'(0)=1, \psi(0)=1, \psi'(0)=0$ .

---

Another.  Define sequences $p_n, q_n$ by
$$
p_n = p_{n-1}+\frac{p_{n-2}}{n^2(n+1)^2},\qquad p_{-1}=1, p_0=1,
\\
q_n = q_{n-1}+\frac{q_{n-2}}{n^2(n+1)^2},\qquad q_{-1}=0,q_0=1 .
$$
Then
$$
\frac{1}{D_4} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_n}{q_n} \approx 1.243 .
$$
But here the sequences converge,
$p = \lim_{n\to\infty}p_n \approx 1.293,
q = \lim_{n\to\infty}q_n \approx 1.040$.  The recurrences yield absolutely convergent expressions,
$$
p =
1+{\frac {1}{ 1 ^2  2 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 2 ^2  3 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 3 ^2 
 4 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 3 ^2  4
 ^2  1 ^2  2 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 
4 ^2  5 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 4 ^2  5 ^2  1 ^2  2 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{
 4 ^2  5 ^2  2 ^2  3
 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 5 ^2  6 ^2 }}+{
\frac {1}{ 5 ^2  6 ^2  1 ^2 2 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 5 ^2  6 ^2 
 2 ^2  3 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 5
 ^2  6 ^2  3 ^2  4 ^2 }}+{
\frac {1}{ 5 ^2  6 ^2  3 ^2  4 ^2  1 ^2  2 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{
 6 ^2  7 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 6
 ^2  7 ^2  1 ^2  2 ^2 }}+{
\frac {1}{ 6 ^2  7 ^2  2 ^2  3 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 6 ^2  7 ^2 
 3 ^2  4 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 6
 ^2  7 ^2  3 ^2  4 ^2  1 ^2  2 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 6 ^2 
 7 ^2  4 ^2  5 ^2 }}+{\frac {1
}{ 6 ^2  7 ^2  4 ^2  5
 ^2  1 ^2  2 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 
6 ^2  7 ^2  4 ^2  5 ^2  2 ^2  3 ^2 }} +\cdots ,
\\
q =
1+{\frac {1}{ 2 ^2  3 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 3 ^2  4 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 4 ^2 
 5 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 4 ^2  5
 ^2  2 ^2  3 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 
5 ^2  6 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 5 ^2  6 ^2  2 ^2  3 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{
 5 ^2  6 ^2  3 ^2  4
 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 6 ^2  7 ^2 }}+{
\frac {1}{ 6 ^2  7 ^2  2 ^2  3 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 6 ^2  7 ^2 
 3 ^2  4 ^2 }}+{\frac {1}{ 6
 ^2  7 ^2  4 ^2  5 ^2 }}+{
\frac {1}{ 6 ^2  7 ^2  4 ^2  5 ^2  2 ^2  3 ^2 }} +\cdots .
$$

Is there a possibility of a closed form for these?

Comment: Ah, this is promising! The closed-form for $D_4$ is a ratio analogous to $D_1$, and the one for $1/D_4$ deserves a further look. Can the method evaluate other "natural" quadratic progressions, say $b_k = n^2+n+1$?

Comment: Per Mathematica convention, the cfrac expansion of $1/D_4$ is [1,4,9,16,…]. We seek $x=[1,3,7,13,…]$.